# Problems displaying graphics in Java

Tags: java, swing, graphics

I'm writing a simulation in Java, but don't have a lot of experience working with Graphics objects. I've written a class

```
public class RoadNetwork extends JPanel {
    BufferedImage truck1;

    public RoadNetwork() throws IOException{
        truck1 = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("Truck.png"));
    }

    protected void paintcomponent (Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawImage(car1, 0, 0, 100, 100, this);
    }
}
```

In my main function, I initialize the class as follows:

```
JFrame F1 = new JFrame();
F1.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
GridBagConstraints constraints = new GridBagConstraints();
F1.setSize(1280,760);
RoadNetwork roadnetwork = new RoadNetwork();
roadnetwork.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500,500));
roadnetwork.setVisible(true);
constraints.gridx = 40;
constraints.gridy = 40;
F1.add(roadnetwork, constraints);
F1.setVisible(true);
```

However, I just get a grey frame as output, with no image. I've tested the image by adding it as a separate ImageIcon into the frame, and that works. However, I can't seem to get the RoadNetwork class to display in the frame. Should I call the paintcomponent function somehow? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From your code, you have a wrong method there.

```
protected void paintcomponent (Graphics g) {
```

is not called for paint.

```
protected void paintComponent (Graphics g) {
```

is correct name of the method, that will override parents one and this one is called by JVM.

Comment: And add an @Override annotation when your intention is to override a method. That way, if you make a typo again, the compiler will detect it and throw an error because the method doesn't reall override anything.